# Buscar por string no Banco de dados SQL / PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-select

Boa noite,

Eu tenho o seguinte select que é pra buscar usuarios de acordo com sua categoria:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM app_usuarios WHERE  cat = '$categ'
```

$categ é a variável que eu recebo dinamicamente de acordo com a escolha do usuário.

Eu tenho as seguintes categorias cadastradas no banco: A, B, C, **D,** **DM**, E.

Só que quando a busca pede o retorno das categorias "D" e "DM" o resultado volta vazio, ele só retorna valores quando a opçao escolhida é A, B, C e E.

O que esta errado no meu select ??

Obrigada. 
Abraço

Comment: Por favor, poste a parte do seu html que contém este formulário.

Comment: Mas o problema nao está no html e sim no SELECT .. ele esta retornando os dados .. o problema é a comparação das strings quando tem inicio semelhantes.

Comment: Verifique se a Letra da Categoria esta também em Maiúscula, pois o sql diferencia letras maiúsculas e minusculas, utilize    UPPER(): Assim: $consulta = "SELECT * FROM app_usuarios WHERE  UPPER(cat) = UPPER('$categ') ou utilize a variável de escape do php $consulta = "SELECT * FROM app_usuarios WHERE  cat = '".$categ."';

Comment: Seu select está ok, exceto que você não fechou a string nem tem o ponto e vírgula, mas pode ter sido na hora de colar (se não ia dar erro de sintaxe). Assim, se `$categ` for qualquer um destes valores, ele deve retornar algo se o banco conter estes dados. Para te ajudar, temos que eliminar a possibilidade de o formulário não estar enviando o parâmetro correto. Se você já fez isto, pode então colocar na resposta o resultado de `print_r($categ)` antes desta linha? ou um `print_r($consulta)` depois dela. Para te ajudar a debugar.

Comment: Uma outra coisa @Paulinha, fora do escopo da sua pergunta, apenas a título de sugestão: do jeito que está seu código, ele está vulnerável a `SQL Injection`. Não se coloca dentro uma query um valor recebido direto do usuário. Ele tem que ser sanitizado antes. Sugiro usar alternativas como Mysqli ou PDO, e usar conceitos como prepare statements, por exemplo.

Comment: oi Pessoal .. obrigada ai pelas orientações.. o tratamento para injection foi feito.. ele esta protegido. Sobre a o que o Marcus Italo comentou.. os dados da categoria estao exatamente assim no banco.. se eu trocar os usuarios com categoria DJ e colocar D o select funciona.. Se eu trocar onde tem D e colocar DJ o select funciona.. O problema é quando existe no banco usuarios com classe D e DJ juntas.. dai ele nao traz nenhum dos dois...Mas se eu deixar uma delas por exemplo dai o select traz resultados.

Comment: Pode então adicionar na pergunta o resultado de `print_r($categ)` antes desta linha? ou um `print_r($consulta)` depois dela?

Comment: quando eu seleciono a categoria D ou DJ nao aparece nada .. quando eu seleciono A, o que aparece é o  seguinte:

Comment: $consulta = "SELECT * FROM app_usuarios WHERE  cat = 'A'

Comment: Como assim não aparece nada? `$consulta` em branco ou `$categ` em branco?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52332/discussion-between-paulinha-and-mrlew).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução encontrada foi a utilização de um LIKE, na busca :

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM app_usuarios WHERE  cat LIKE '$categ'
```

Comment: Obrigada!!!! Funcionando agora!